# How to remove elements of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` I need to extract 2 values or remove the values I don't need from the dictionary in the example below I need to remove id and NumberValue. any of you knows how can I do that?

```
Array: (
        {
            customerUS= {
                DisplayName = "level";
                InternalName = "Number 2";
                NumberValue = 1;
                id = xwrf
            },
            customerCAN= {
                DisplayName = "PurchaseAmount";
                InternalName = "Number 1";
                NumberValue = 3500;
                id = adf;
            };
        }
      )
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: OK first things first, have you examined how that JSON relates to the objects used to store it in memory (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`)?  Once you know that have you looked at the class reference and searched for your issue?  You don't seem to want to learn, you just want someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, You can not **remove/insert/update** value in *(immutable)* `NSDictionary/NSArray` you need to convert `NSDictionary/NSArray`  to  *(mutable)* `NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray`.

such like

```
NSArray *myArr = ....;    
NSMutableArray *newMutableArr = [myArr mutableCopy];
```

Then you can change in **newMutableArr**.

Such like

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < newMutableArr.count ; i ++)
{
   [[newMutableArr objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectForKey:@"id"];
   [[newMutableArr objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectForKey:@"NumberValue"];
}
```

**EDITED:**

Without Use of `for loop` and `removeObjectForKey`, if you have array of dictionary and both are mutable then you can also delete a key and its object from all elements of the array like this:

```
[newMutableArr makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:) withObject:@"id"];
[newMutableArr makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:) withObject:@"NumberValue"];
```

Comment: there is no way of doing this programmatically?

Comment: @HelenaM - what so you mean ?? "there is no way of doing this programmatically?"

Comment: @HelenaM you can also remove loop if you have one element of array and dictionary.. other with you must need to use for loop. But what is problem with for loop ??

Comment: @iPatel makeObjectsPerformSelector work for me. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to read Apple documents.

For modifying any Collection object after it is created, you need the mutable version.
For `NSDictionary` we have `NSMutableDictionary`. Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey%3a).

We have a method for removing objects:

```
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey
```

There are other methods as well. You can easily refer them in the above mentioned documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Find out removeObjectForKey for deleting record from NSMutabledictionary.

removeObjectForKey pass the key value whatever you have like

all this are your key
                **DisplayName,
                InternalName, 
                NumberValue,
                id**

do like this

```
removeObjectForKey:@"id";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to convert the array to mutable array and then you can remove the key-value pairs from dictionary.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [yourArray mutableCopy];
for(int i=0;i<mutableArray.count;i++){
  NSMutableDictionary *outerDictionary = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
  for(NSString *key in outerDictionary.allKeys){
    NSMutableDictionary *innerDictionary = [outerDictionary objectForKey:key];
    [innerDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"id"];
    [innerDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"NumberValue"];
  }
}
```